# Best way to apply a void function to a parameter pack

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++20

I would like to write a function that applies a function to each element of a parameter pack. The functions returns a `std::tuple` with the results of each invocation.

However, if the applied function returns `void`, I have to do something else, so I have a different overload for this case. But, almost all the ways I've found to expand the parameter pack do not work with `void` expressions, so I had to resort to what you see below, which seems a weird trick.

```
template<typename F, typename ...Args>
  requires requires { std::tuple{std::declval<F>(Args)...}; }
auto for_each(F f, Args ...args) {
  return std::tuple{f(args)...};
}

template<typename F, typename ...Args>
auto for_each(F f, Args ...args)
  [[maybe_unused]] int a[] = {(f(Members), 0)...};
}
```

Note that I have to declare a unused variable and mark it with the attribute.
Which is the best way to obtain the expected result here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This trick is the way to go pre-C++17, except that you need an extra `, 0` in the array to support zero-length packs.

In C++17 and newer, use a fold expression: `(f(args), ...);`.

---

Note that you forgot perfect forwarding. You should be doing `F &&f, Args &&... args`, and then `(f(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);`, and similarly for the first function.

---

I also question the value of having such a function. I'd understand doing this to a tuple, but if you already have a pack, you can do this manually at the call site.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think about the fold expression! Regarding the usefulness of the function, this is just a stripped down example of a more complex thing. Thanks again.